# What happened to the "Votes work differently on meta" part of the FAQ?

Tags: support, meta-faq, help-center

There used to be a part of the FAQ explaining how votes on meta were different. Often the first comment on a question from a new meta user that was getting downvotes would be a link to that part of the FAQ. In most cases, it worked, and got people to understand that this was disagreement, not "bad quality" votes.

Now that we've moved to the new Help Center, I can't seem to find that section anywhere. Can someone either tell me where it's hiding, or can we reinstate it for all the meta sites? Otherwise, this is a pretty useless help center.

Comment: Perhaps a not so subtle hint that votes *shouldn't* be different on meta?

Comment: @Servy: Maybe...

Answer (score 11):

It's located under the help question [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/whats-meta)

Don't worry, the old [FAQ link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) will redirect there properly, too.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was somewhere... (doesn't that say something about the help center?)

Comment: This answer is correct. Also, @Linuxios we're going to be adding in a search box for the help center - I know it's a little difficult to figure out where things are right now, but hopefully that problem will be completely eliminated when we add search. :)

Comment: @Linuxios - I think is says more about being used to things the way they were...

Comment: @Laura: Perhaps that particular topic could be pinned on Meta sites rather than just bumped up the list a few spots?

Comment: @Laura, Oded; Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Linuxios Obligatory [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: @AsheeshR: Yes.